# If $a$ and $b$ have order $n$ and $m,$ and say $a^p=b^q$ for some integers $p$ and $q$. How many elements are there of the form $a^sb^t$?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

> If $a$ and $b$ have order $n$ and $m$, and say $a^p=b^q$ for some integers $p, q$  with $0<p\leq n$ and $0<q\leq m$. How many elements are there of the form $a^sb^t$?

I tried solving a few examples. I took $n=4$ and $m=5$, and assumed $a^2=b^4$. Now, all elements of the form $a^2b^s$ reduce to some power of $b$. Also, all elements of the form $a^pb^s$ reduce to some product of a power of $a$ and power of $b$, where the power of $a$ is computed under arithmetic modulo $2$.

So I think there will be $pq$ distinct elements of the form $a^sb^t$.

Can we get a proof of this result?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Mathematics, Saikat. Thank you for clearly setting out what you yourself have tried in approaching the problem. It may be easier for the community to help if you take a couple of minutes to write up your formulae in MathJax, please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You need to put `$` signs around the math expressions for the formatting to take effect.

Comment: Your example can't possibly happen.  If $a$ has order $4$ and $a^2=b^4$, then $1=a^4=b^8=b^3 (\text{ since } b^5=1) \neq 1.$  I'm pretty sure that if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $m=p$ and $n=q$.

Comment: It might help to look at the [amalgamated free product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product#Generalization:_Free_product_with_amalgamation) $$\langle a\mid a^n\rangle\ast_{a^p=b^q}\langle b\mid b^m\rangle.$$

Comment: Does [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113532/if-a-and-b-have-order-n-and-m-and-say-ap-bq-for-some-integers-p-a#comment6416415_3113532) make sense, @saulspatz?

Comment: @Shaun I have no idea what the amalgamated free product is, so I can't answer.

Comment: Fair enough, @saulspatz; thank you anyway :)

Comment: [Here's a discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49113986#49113986) of my suggestion to use an amalgamated free product.

Answer (score 1):

Your result does not hold. I will give you a hint to help you find the actual result yourself:

> If $a$ and $b$ have order $n$ and $m$, and say $a^p=b^q$ for some integers $0<p\leq n$ and $0<q\leq m$, then every element can be written *uniquely* in the form $a^sb^t$ where $0\leq s<n$ and $0\leq t<q$.

(Note the "$0\leq t<q$" and not "$0\leq t<m$".)